# Linux virtual machines cannot connect to each other via virtualbox network

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, ping, adapter

I have created two linux virtual machines in virtualbox, one for server and one for client. But these two cannot connect to each other via virtualbox network. The pings are not reachable after giving them proper ip addresses. I tried all types of adapters in virtualbox; bridged, NAT, internal networking but nothing works. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1312950/how-to-make-joomla-and-mysql-in-separated-virtualbox-machines-communicating

Comment: I found a solution: https://superuser.com/a/1313413/814514